# Convert PDF to JPG using ImageMagick (PHP and LINUX)

Tags: php, linux, imagemagick, imagick

I am trying to convert PDF to JPG using the "convert" command:

```
convert "ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_PDF" "ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_JPG"
```

It works fine from the terminal. But the browsers hangs when executed using:

```
exec( 'convert "ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_PDF" "ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_JPG"', $output );
```

I tried to check the permissions, same result.

I even tried to check if the command is available in the environment path:

```
which convert
/usr/bin/convert

which gs
/usr/bin/gs

and the server environment path is: 
"/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: PHP version? Safe mode? Try other exec() alternatives also like passthru()

Comment: PHP Version 5.2.6, Safe_mode is off. I will try the passthru and get back to you thanks

Comment: Even the passthru is not completing, and it does not show any result